# I keep Blowing up my i2C (ISO1540) isolator when plugging and unplugging my battery

Tags: battery-charging, i2c, isolation, damage, smbus

I am using a [ISO1540](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso1540.pdf?ts=1695357325118&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FISO1540) to read the SMBus of some [BB2590](https://www.bren-tronics.com/bt-70791ck.html) batteries. The relevant part of the circuit is shown in the images below

The issue that I am having is that sometimes when connecting or disconnecting the batteries, U14 gets damaged (no signs of damage, no short circuit or anything visible) and I stop getting telemetry of the Cell 1 of the battery until the IC is replaced with a new one.

The connector of the battery is rigid and that allows all the cells to connect 'at the same time'.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the fact that U14's Ground is the Positive side of Cell 0 of the battery and maybe during the connection/disconnection process there is a voltage spike or similar, but not 100% sure.

Anyone has any pointers on how I could protect the ISO1540 to avoid damaging it with the normal use of the battery?.

EDIT:
J10 is a JST, J5 and J6 is an XT30, they are wired to a connector similar to this one:
[tacticaleng.com/bb-2590-smbus-male-connector](https://tacticaleng.com/bb-2590-smbus-male-connector)

With a PCB ike this one:
[tacticaleng.com/pcb-2590](https://tacticaleng.com/pcb-2590)

So when the battery is plugged in, it is plugged in to the connector in the links. J5, J6 and J10 are "hard wired" to the PCB

[image: Wiring of the ISO1540]
[image: Battery input]
[[image: 5V regulators for the Battery side of the ISO15403]
[image: BB2590 Battery]

Comment: Hi Pepe, welcome to EE. To me it looks like your on the right track, U14s Vcc2 gets twice the voltage U12s Vcc2 gets, thanks to the bridge between GND_C0 and GNDS.

Comment: @MiNiMe I cannot follow your point: U14.VCC2 - U14.GND2 <= 5 V. The < 16 V offset between U14.GND2 and GNDS should not be relevant for an isolator.

Comment: Do you know the internal schematic behind connector J10? This would help to understand the issue. What ist the connect / disconnect sequence between J5, J6 and J10?

Comment: J10 is a JST, J5 and J6 is an XT30, they are wired to a connector similar to this one:
https://www.tacticaleng.com/bb-2590-smbus-male-connector with a PCB ike this one https://www.tacticaleng.com/pcb-2590    so when the battery is plugged in, it is plugged in to the conector in the links. J5, J6 and J10 are "hard wired" to the PCB

Comment: Is the regulator not blowing instead (or in addition)? A 180V TVS is *way* too high for a 28V regulator.

Comment: @Jens Not sure I follow either, it's just something I noticed. If the batteries powers the monitoring system, you could get some weird path for electricity to take, thanks to that GND bridge.

Comment: @TimWilliams The regulator has blown some times, mainly while plugging and unplugging the battery when the circuit is live. The ISO failing when plugging and un-plugging while the circuit is not energised. I don't know if that has any difference. Regarding the TVS diode, I will replace it for a smaller value, any recommendations?

Comment: @MiNiMe Yeah the ground link could be the culprit, but I don't know how to make keep the batteries in series and still be able to read the SMBus, this is the first time I work with a battery with two cells and a smbus per cell.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the grounding. At least, I don't think I see it. It's very hard to tell with the net label interconnections. It would be a lot easier to tell if everything were wired together, on one schematic. Anyway, hot plugging into ceramic capacitors is a top culprit of dead power supply questions here. A TVS with clamping voltage under 28, and nominal rated voltage above battery Vmax, will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The earths for the two I2C busses are pins 2 and 5 on the round connector, and may mate before or after the 'pogo-pins' of the 2 SMB busses make contact.
You have to assume that things may end up 30V apart, briefly, if the ends of the series pair connect before the test circuit connects to the middle.
If the chip ends up doing the splits seeing a voltage between SCL and SDA because earth breaks first (or makes last) then it may go into SCR latch up and fail once power is properly applied. Series resistances of ~  hundred ohms to the pogo pins and if need be diodes up and down from clock and data and data to ground and supply (or a ~ 4V zener between the clk/data pin and ground pins next to the chip to clamp down to -0.6 V and up to Vzener ) will limit the stress. The reg will die either when there is  an over-voltage on the input, or a voltage on the output (perhaps a load side capacitor holding up) and a low impedance on the input side, so a large current flows the wrong way. Again current limiting resistances (between Batt CO and the capacitor on pin 2 of the reg )turn a dead short fail into a survivable overload. That resistor should not drop more than 5-10V on the largest current the interface would draw working normally.